# UL LI click is hiding the UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a UL LI list such that when the word "LIST" is clicked on, the LI elements will be displayed and vice-versa. However, if an LI is clicked on the entire list gets hidden again. I'd like to make it such that if an LI is clicked on, it wont hide my list as I'd like to add functionality for the LI click later.

Here is the code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul li {
    display: none;
}
ul li:before{ content:"- ";}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

$('ul').click(function(){

     if ($('ul > li').css('display') == 'none') {

        $('ul > li').show();

    }
    else {
    $('ul > li').hide()

    }

});

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
    List
    <li>1234</li>
    <li>5678</li>
    <li>0123</li>
</ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is invalid html, the only thing that goes directly inside `<ul></ul>` or `<ol></ol>` is `<li>`. Also `$('ul > li')` selects all the `li` elements in all 'ul' elements so you need to edit your selector to only select the element you are wanting to hide/show

Comment: @PatrickEvans I think you mean the only thing inside `ul` or `ol` is a `li`.

Comment: @Twisty, that I do, corrected

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kgvx49k4/4/ as an example will work. As other said, your HTML is incorrect. Or use `toggle`, https://jsfiddle.net/kgvx49k4/6/

Comment: In your CSS, you're hiding all `li`, why?

Comment: Also, since `ul` has no `li` shown, there is no rendered content to click on, so you can't click on `ul` to execute the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out above you can't just stick text in a `ul` like that. A `ul` should only have `li` elements within it. A cleaner approach is something like this that shows and hides the `ul` element instead of all the `li`s inside it with a control external to the `ul`.

Also as pointed out below there is a much better way to handle this all to make sure you aren't dealing with every `ul` on the page. By using class selectors and the built in jquery functions.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/erjfghf0/

HTML:

```
<a class="showHideLink">List</a>
<ul class="showHideList">
    <li>1234</li>
    <li>5678</li>
    <li>0123</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.showHideLink').click(
    function (event) {
        $(this).next('.showHideList').toggle();
    }
);
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That would hide all `li` elements inside all `ul` elements, you code suffers from the same problem as OP's you are using the wrong selector

Comment: You're right. I fixed it. Its because I copied and pasted the code. =O

Comment: It's still not likely what the op wants, as you are now just hiding **all** ul's, since the ul is a sibling to the anchor element you would do `$(this).sibling("ul").first()`, or give the list an id and select it that way

Comment: Well at this point I was simply pointing out how to do this differently. Its not wrong. I wasn't going to go into explaining selectors in this. It was an example on showing and hiding the ul. Is there much improvement needed in their code and the code above. Yes. Would I use this code in production. No. Does it show how to not have free floating text in a ul and to hide and show the ul on a click. Yes.

Comment: `css()` will only check the first `li` in the list. You could use jQuery's `toggle()` function on the `ul` instead: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: There I have fully updated answer. Is everyone happy now? =]

Answer (score 1):

Since the UL has nothing to render, due to all the LI being hidden, you need to render the event action on something else. Here is my suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/LL948r6f/

**HTML**

```html
List (<a href="#" id='toggleLink'>Toggle</a>)
<ul>
  <li>1234</li>
  <li>5678</li>
  <li>0123</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "- ";
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggleLink, ul').click(function() {
        console.log("List Items display: " + $('ul li').css('display'));
        if ($('ul li').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('ul li').show();
        } else {
            $('ul li').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You suffered from copy/paste syndrome too. =]

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I see what you guys are discussing, but maybe I am missing it. When I review the HTML in FireBug, `ul` is displayed, yet `li` are hidden. The only other option would be to add ID or classes to the elements to make them more select-able.

Comment: I think that one the selectors they were using would be selecting every `ul` on the page. And two the question seems to suggest they want to hide the `ul` but instead they are hiding every `li`. At this point I'm not sure about anything. But I think we can all agree the code all over this question has much room for improvement. I simply wasn't trying to rewrite it for them but to show them a path and let them learn on their own with other questions but my answer got so many comments I ended rewriting the whole thing anyway. c'est la vie.

Comment: re: 1) Yes, for this example that's okay, in production that could be bad. re: 2) Setting `ul` to hidden would make it no longer rendered and you would never be able to click it again, unless programmatically. So I agree there. Hopefully they learn.

Comment: Exactly. Hence the reason you and I both moved the hiding/showing control outside the `ul`.